# The method compare(long, long) is undefined for the type Long

Tags: java, comparator

I need to make a Comparator to sort my List of objects by one of its variables which is of `long` type.

```
public class ParticipantIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
        final List<Participant> participants;       
        public ParticipantIndexComparator(ArrayList<Integer> numbersToSort) {
            participants=new ArrayList<Participant>();
            for (int i=0;i<numbersToSort.size();i++)
            { participants.add(i,competition.participant.get(numbersToSort.get(i))); participants.get(i).comparator=numbersToSort.get(i);}

        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            long l1 = participants.get(i1).kpTime.get(kpSelected); 
            long l2 = participants.get(i2).kpTime.get(kpSelected);
              return Long.compare(l1, l2);
        }


    }
```

But   `return Long.compare(l1, l2);` is invalid - "The method compare(long, long) is undefined for the type Long".

Seems like I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: `participants.get(i).comparator=numbersToSort.get(i)` Why are you assigning signle number to something named `comparator`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This method exists since Java 7. You're probably using a Java 6 or even older version of Java. In these previous versions, you can simply use

```
Long.valueOf(l1).compareTo(Long.valueOf(l2));
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare%28long,%20long%29) is your friend. Read it.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: the signature is correct. The OP wants to compare integers. Not longs. These integers are used to find a long value associated to the integer and should be sorted according to this long value. Just like if you sorted persons of type Person by lastName of type String.

Comment: JB Nizet , exactly!! I'm using it with Java 6 because I code for Android

Comment: Thanks alot ! I've been asking this for 2 щк 3 times different way and people always were trying to compare two indexes to variables, not the variables themselves. It's a common thing here that people doesn't read the question. For example, when I was looking for a way to Inflate views in Android in several rows same way as the text does - when 1st line is filled - it goes from the beginning of the next line. My answer was a simple GridView, but people started to give me advices on working with text

Answer (score 1):

If you experience Integer.compare being undefined after importing a Maven project into Eclipse, check the project properties to insure that it is using a 1.7 JRE. For some reason the import associated a 1.6 JRE with my project even though the POM, and my system default was 1.7.*.